# group and/or rewrite an existing array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using a database system for some kind of gaming competition where players can team up and participate in events. Right now players have their own database, then there is a database for teams (team id, name, join password, etc) and a database where I save which player (player name/id is in which team name/id). My database call gives me an array with team_name, username, etc. I wanted to group the users by a common team_name value which worked, but I'm not able to rewrite it according to my needs.

I want to build some kind of api for my personal use in C# application. There I want the output of my script to be json and I want to show all the teams with some details. Right now im using the following code:

```
$team_keys = array();
    foreach ($team_data AS $k => $sub_array)
    {
        $this_team = $sub_array['team_name'];
        $team_keys[$this_team][$k] = array('username' => $sub_array['username']);
    }
echo json_encode($team_keys, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This gives me an output like this:

```
{
    "Team1": {
        "0": {
            "username": "player1"
        },
        "1": {
            "username": "player2"
        },
        "22": {
            "username": "player3"
        }
    },
    "Team2": {
        "2": {
            "username": "player4"
        },
        "3": {
            "username": "player5"
        }, .....
}
```

But I want to achieve something like:

```
    {
    "team_name": "Team1",
    "team_password": "secret",
    "creation_timestamp": "123456789",
    "players": [
        "Player1",
        "Player2",
        "Player3"
    ]
}, ....
```

I tried tons of different approaches but I was simply not able to regroup and rewrite the array to my needs. Hopefully someone can help me out.

EDIT: $team_data looks like this (I'm using JOIN to join my user, teams, and team_member tables to get all the data together):

```
array(83) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(8) "Player1"
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(8) "Team1"
    ["team_password"]=>
    string(7) "secret"
    ["team_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(11) "Player2"
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(8) "Team1"
    ["team_password"]=>
    string(7) "secret"
    ["team_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(8) "Player3"
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(10) "Team2"
    ["team_password"]=>
    string(6) "ultrasecret"
    ["team_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  },...
```

Comment: Could you please post the $team_data input, too. Perhaps as php array, just sample data how they are organized! It's hard to help you without.

Comment: Hi Kordi, I edited my question with the relevant data you asked for :)

Comment: `player3` is from `team2`, isn't he? where do you want to take `creation_timestamp` ?

Comment: yes player3 is from team2, I'm not outputting the timestamp yet but its available in the database for later usage. Basically it as a list of the players that have a team.

Comment: @wordiboi wrote an answer :-)

Comment: Thank you very very much, this helped me a lot and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So Input was the following data**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(5) "Team1"
    ["username"]=>
    string(7) "player1"
    ["team_password"]=>
    string(6) "secret"
    ["team_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(5) "Team1"
    ["username"]=>
    string(7) "player2"
    ["team_password"]=>
    string(6) "secret"
    ["team_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(5) "Team2"
    ["username"]=>
    string(7) "player1"
    ["team_password"]=>
    string(6) "secret"
    ["team_id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["team_name"]=>
    string(5) "Team2"
    ["username"]=>
    string(7) "player2"
    ["team_password"]=>
    string(6) "secret"
    ["team_id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

**This is my code with my testset of $team_data**

```
<?php

$team_data = array(array('team_name' => 'Team1', 'username' => 'player1', 'team_password' => 'secret', 'team_id' => 1)
,array('team_name' => 'Team1', 'username' => 'player2', 'team_password' => 'secret', 'team_id' => 1)
,array('team_name' => 'Team2', 'username' => 'player1', 'team_password' => 'secret', 'team_id' => 2)
,array('team_name' => 'Team2', 'username' => 'player2', 'team_password' => 'secret', 'team_id' => 2)
);

$team_keys = array();
foreach ($team_data AS $player_dara) {
    if (!isset($team_keys[$player_dara['team_id']])) {
        $team_keys[$player_dara['team_id']] = array();
        $team_keys[$player_dara['team_id']]['team_name'] = $player_dara['team_name'];
        $team_keys[$player_dara['team_id']]['team_id'] = $player_dara['team_id'];
        $team_keys[$player_dara['team_id']]['secret'] = $player_dara['secret'];
        $team_keys[$player_dara['team_id']]['players'] = array();
    }
    $team_keys[$player_dara['team_id']]['players'][] = $player_dara['username'];
}


echo json_encode(array_values($team_keys), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Output**

```
[
 {
   "team_name": "Team1",
   "team_id": 1,
   "secret": null,
   "players": [
     "player1",
     "player2"
   ]
 },
 {
  "team_name": "Team2",
  "team_id": 2,
  "secret": null,
  "players": [
    "player1",
    "player2"
  ]
 }
]
```